# How can I be able to code Selenium web page testing on the desktop Plus native app testing on an Android mobile device, in a single test application?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium-desktop, appium-java

I have a scenario where I need to
**a.)Given** I Go to a web page dashboard, configure the users, groups, devices then save the settings, which gets pushed to the Android(or iOS) device I had physically connected to my mac(or Windows).
**b.)When** I go to the Android(or iOS) device and open my native app do some selections/actions. Based on the settings I pushed through my above web dashboard, I would get some indicators displayed on the native mobile app plus on the web dashboard too.
**c.)Then** I go to the dashboard on the desktop webpage and validate the same indicators, which I have observed on the native app on the mobile device

All this round trip of Desktop Web page --> Native app on the mobile device ---> Back at the desktop webpage for validations, should happen in the same test application/program.

> I have completely set up appium, selenium libraries in a maven project
> in Eclipse IDE, which is able to run a test purely mobile device based
> only.

**`How can I proceed to include Selenium web page testing in to this and combine it together with WebDriver, AppiumWebDriver ?`**

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that now the Appium code written as a Java program, as part of Maven or Gradle project will allow both WebDriver instance to manage desktop browser and MobileDriver to manage the mobile device browser to exist at the same time and you can even shift from desktop to mobile and back to do your testing activity at any time.

I tried in my Java program to instantiate both the drivers and ran a test code and it ran successfully. But I have yet to verify the full cycle of desktop to mobile and back testing still though.